# XCopyArea fails for X11 bitmap (Pixmap with depth 1)

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I want to do texture atlas with Xlib in X11. I Created a pixmap by loading pixel data from an image file which contains all sprites that will be used as texture. I can copy part of texture atlas pixmap (single spirit) to another pixmap created as off-screen drawable successfully.

Here comes the problem. I want the texture copied to the destination pixmap with partial transparent so that there will not be a background rectangle appears behind each spirit. To do that I created a pixmap with depth equals 1 for the whole texture atlas image(500 * 500).

The `pMaskData` is the pixel data with depth 1.

```
Pixmap texAtlasMask = XCreatePixmapFromBitmapData(kTheDisplay, kRootWindow,
        (char*)pMaskData, 500, 500, 1, 0, 1);
```

Then I create a clip_mask pixmap for a single sprite, the size of the sprite is 16*16, by first creating a 1 depth pixmap:

```
Pixmap clipMask = XCreatePixmap(kTheDisplay, kRootWindow, 16, 16, 1);
```

then use the following call to fill the content of `clipMask`:

```
// Error occurs here 
// reqest code: 62:X_CopyArea               
// Error code: 8:BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
 XCopyArea(kTheDisplay, texAtlasMask, clipMask, m_gc, 0, 0,16, 16, 0, 0);
```

After that:

```
XSetClipMask(kTheDisplay, m_gc, clipMask);

// Copy source spirit to backing store pixmap
XSetClipOrigin(kTheDisplay, m_gc, destX, destY);
XCopyArea(kTheDisplay, m_symAtlas, m_backStore, m_gc, srcLeft, srcTop,
          width, height, destX, destY);
```

The `m_symAtlas` is the texture atlas pixmap, `m_backStore` is the destination pixmap we are drawing to.

As listed above error happens in the first call of XCopyArea. I tried XCopyPlane, but nothing changed.

And I play around with XCopyArea and found that as long as the pixmap 's depth is 32 the XCopyArea works fine, it fails when the depth is not 32. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @Scheff In this project Qt or other high-level graphics libraries are not allowed. I need to implement with opengl and X11 etc. The texture is true color, just the mask is 1 depth.

Comment: _The texture is true color, just the mask is 1 depth._ That's surprising. (I don't say ...impossible.) Usually, transparent images use RGBA pixels with each channel 8 bit (resulting in 32 bit per pixel). Yet another question: What file format does your images have? Is it necessary to make it a GUI application? I mean, to load, process, and store images, you could also make a console application assuming you have the resp. lib for loading and saving the image files.

Comment: @Scheff The image is RGB pixels and 24 bit per pixel with background color white(255,255,255). The spirits will not use (255,255,255). So that I can create a mask where the white colored pixel is '0' and the others '1'.  This is not a GUI application , its a graphical library indeed.

Comment: When I write OpenGL code, I try to leave the GUI stuff extra. This makes it easier to re-use the OpenGL code in multiple applications e.g. a desktop (authoring) tool vs. a HMD-player. Concerning the images (for textures), I use an image library with no dependencies to any GUI lib. Actually, after loading an image, it's just an array of bytes with some additional administrative data. Respectively, copying, modifying, or something results in "some simple integer arithmetics".

Comment: "_spirits_" = "sprites"?

Comment: What OpenGL texture format do you have in mind for 1 bit alpha? `GL_RGB5_A1`? When arranging your texture atlas, it could be worth to do the pixel (channel) transformation as well.

Comment: Sorry, it should be sprites, poor English.

Comment: It seems Xlib does not deal with the alpha channel. As far as I know, It uses clipping mask to do transparent.

Comment: If you got the feeling that I try to convince you to do it without X11 - your feeling is right. There is no X11 needed to load an image file - but the resp. image loader function. The conversion of images is usually some kind of copying, (spatial or color) scaling, bit-shifting, etc. To handle different pixel formats in X11 can become complicated, but scaling pixel values in a for-loop rather simple. Of course, it's possible to make things more difficult when you consider gamma functions or other sophisticated things. However, IMHO adding Xlib makes things more complicated at best.

Comment: It looks like your GC is wrong. You need a separate GC for each depth.

Comment: "This is not a GUI application". Then it has **absolutely no reason** being an X11 application. X is not an image manipulation server. It's a **display** server.

Comment: I will try to create a separate GC. See if it works.

Comment: You should not create a separate GC. You should **stop** developing your application, scrap the code, and start again without X. Just sayin'.

Comment: Then what should I use to render off-screen?

Comment: Any way, the new GC makes the error gone! :)

Comment: There are many libraries you can use, I would look at Cairo Graphics which is cross-platform and can render both on- and off-screen on a variety of devices. If you are focusing on textures, then Mesa is an OpenGL implementation that can render to an off-screen buffer. Also look at OpenCV image manipulation facilities.

Comment: I considered Cario at first, but give up on it since I need a small library. Maybe I can give it a chance again.

Comment: An OpenGL implementation is already done.

Comment: @n.m.  Why a separate GC is needed?  At least I can learn from that.

Comment: If you need a very small simple library, write one yourself, it's not that hard if you don't require very high performance.

Comment: This is mentioned in the manual page of `XCreateGC`: "The GC can be used with any destination drawable having the same root and depth as the specified drawable. Use with other drawables results in a BadMatch error"